# jQuery undesired effect from 'tr td:first-child'

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic `HTML` table that I create in `PHP` from a query. After it's created the user can click an edit button and certain cells become editable. When they're done they press the save button and a loop initiates running through the data and storing it in an array. *Almost* everything works, there is a small problem of getting the value of the job# column, it's putting both values in one index of my array. I made a fiddle to show the process [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NuLPC/7/) and illustrate the problem. So as you can see I it's storing all numbers in the last index. I do need all of them, but I would like them to be stored one at a time so they each have their own individual index in the array.

Also I will post the code down here, even though the fiddle I linked is probably more useful

```
var saveEdits = [];

$('#table_edit_projects').click(function () {
    $('#create_project').hide();
    $('#table_edit_projects').hide();
    $('#save_project_te').show();
    $('#cancel_save_project_te').show();
    $('.editable_content_td').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    $('.editable_content_td').addClass('blue_td');
});

$('#save_project_te').click(function () {
    $('#save_project_te').hide();
    $('#cancel_save_project_te').hide();
    $('#create_project').show();
    $('#table_edit_projects').show();
    $('.editable_content_td').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('.editable_content_td').removeClass('blue_td');

    $('.editable_content_td').each(function () {
        saveEdits.push($(this).text());
    });
    var id = $('.contentTable tr td:first-child');
    saveEdits.push($(id).text());
    $.each(saveEdits, function (index, value) {
        alert(index + ': ' + value);
    });

    /*This will be used to send the data and update the table in the database
    $.ajax({    
    url:'core/functions/update_projects.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'saveEdits': saveEdits},
    done: function(data) {
    // this is for testing
    }
    }).fail (function() {
        alert('error');
    }).always(function(data) {                                                  
        alert(data);    
    }); 
    */
    saveEdits = [];
});
```

Comment: Yes, you're selecting *all* cells in the first table column. *Which one* of them do you want when you say you only want one?

Comment: @Bergi I apologize for not being more clear, I actually do want all of them, just not at once, I would like them to be added one at a time in their own individual index. Beno's answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Bergi I edited the question to make it more clear the desired effect I was looking for. This way future readers will understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the selector `$('.contentTable tr td:first-child')` chooses every one of those elements and gets the text from all of them, resulting in `16 17` as you are seeing.

My suggestion is to change a couple of things:
Push the id into the array by adding an additional selector:

```
$('.editable_content_td, .content_td a').each(function () {
    saveEdits.push($(this).text());
});
```

Then remove the code you have that is getting the id - the id should now be at the start of the array

http://jsfiddle.net/NuLPC/8/